# Spring Batch - where does the process run

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I'm trying to wrap my head around Spring Batch, and while many tutorials show great examples of code, i feel like i'm missing how the "spring batch engine" works.

Scenario 1 - On user creation, create user at external service.

1. Web request
2. CreateLocalUser()
3. launch job CreateExternalUser()

CreateExternalUser() can fail because of many reasons, so we want to be able to retry and log errors, which Spring Batch can do for us. Also it's a decoupled process that has nothing to do with the creation of our local user.

Where does the job run? Will it run in the same thread as the web request, which means the end user will have to wait for the job to finish before getting http status 200?

Imagine i have a Web server and a Batch server. I want all jobs to run on the Batch server, but the jobs themselves can be initiated from the Web server. Can Spring Batch do this? Do i need some kind of Queue that i can write to from the Webserver and Consume from the Batch server, where the actual job will begin?

Scenario 2 - Process lines in huge file, start new job for each line

1. Read lines in huge file (1.000.000 lines)
2. Start new job for each line using input parameters from the file.

Processing the 1.000.000 lines is quick and the 1.000.000 new jobs will more or less be started at the same time. Where does these run? Do they run async to the initial job? Will my server be able to handle running all these more or less at the same time.

Additional question:
Is it possible to query Jobs based on a job input parameter. i.e. Scenario 1, i want to show the CreateExternalUser job status / error when viewing my local user with Id 1234 on my web page. CreateExternalUser job has input parameter userId: 1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few questions here so let's go through them one at a time:

**Where does the job run? Will it run in the same thread as the web request, which means the end user will have to wait for the job to finish before getting http status 200?**

That depends on your configuration.  If you use the defaults, then yes.  The job would run in the same thread and the user would be forced to wait until the job completes in order to get the 200.  This obviously isn't a good idea...

Which is why Spring Batch's `SimpleJobLauncher` allows you to inject a `TaskExecutor`.  By configuring your `JobLauncher` to use an async `TaskExecutor` implementation (`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for example), the job would be executed in a different thread, allowing the controller's processing to complete.

Obviously this is all within a single JVM, which bring us to your next question.

**I want all jobs to run on the Batch server, but the jobs themselves can be initiated from the Web server. Can Spring Batch do this? Do i need some kind of Queue that i can write to from the Webserver and Consume from the Batch server, where the actual job will begin?**

Spring Batch contains a module called Spring Batch Integration.  This module provides various capabilities including using messages to launch Spring Batch Jobs.  You can use this to have a remote "batch" server that you can communicate with from the web server.  The communication mechanism is Spring Integration channels so any messaging option backed by SI would be supported (JMS, AMQP, REST, etc).

**Scenario 2 - Process lines in huge file, start new job for each line**
This scenario makes me think you're going down the wrong path for your design.  Can you post a new question that elaborates on this use case?

**Additional question: Is it possible to query Jobs based on a job input parameter**
Job parameters are used to identify `JobInstances` and are fundamental to job identification.  Because of this, yes, you can identify individual job runs based on the parameters.

Comment: Elaboration for Scenario 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558148/spring-batch-process-lines-in-huge-file-start-new-job-for-each-line

Comment: Thanks! Looking at this https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing the individual readers, writers, jobs and steps make sense. What i can't wrap my head around is what lies around the jobs and if this a part of spring batch or something i need to manage myself. i.e. Say i have 10 jobs. 3 need to consume AMQP and run all the time. 3 needs to run every hour (e.g. Scenario 2) and the other 4 i can manually start when i need. What i have learned about Spring Batch is how to define the actual logic of the Job, but not when and how the Job should start. I hope this make sense.

Comment: In addition to that. Say i hook up my solution with Spring Batch Admin, and run a Job that consume AMQP, will each message consumed be shown as a Job in Admin or will the process consuming messages show up as one job.

Comment: Are you using AMQP to launch the jobs or is a single job reading AMQP messages?

Comment: We are using a single job reading AMQP messages. We thought about creating a Job for each message, but instead have created a separate mini status system where we track, Queued, Started, Finished, Error for each message. Spring Batch will run the Consumer process, and this can be viewed in Spring Batch Admin. The Individual messages will not be monitored by Spring Batch, but our mini status system.

Comment: In the case you're describing, Spring Batch Admin will display it as one job.  Within the step processing the messages, the read count will obviously go up, but in general, it will be listed as one job.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This was also why I was questioning creating a new Job for each Message in Scenario 2. But it seems that is not how to use Spring batch. Saving a status for each AMPQ message should be something you do within the job.