# Spring Batch - Process lines in huge file, start new job for each line

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Addition to this question:
[Spring Batch - where does the process run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537310/spring-batch-where-does-the-process-run)

Once every hour i get a huge file with Usage Data for a set of services. A Usage Data line has a UserId and a ServiceId and how long/much the service has been used.

For each Usage Data i need to check which Subscription the User has, and how much the service cost per. unit for this particular Subscription. This will result in a line i can bill to the user.

For each line:

1. Database: Find Subscription by User
2. Database: Find Service cost by Subscription
3. Task: Calculate price
4. Database: Write billing line

It is important to notice that Subscriptions will not always have a cost for a specific service. Because of this each line can fail untill a user adds a cost for the given Subscription and service.

There is alot of logic for each line, and each of these can fail, with a need to rerun.

I have also been thinking of fetching all UserSubscriptions, Subscriptions and SubscriptionServiceCost into memory and then itteration through these, so i will only do a select in the beginning of the flow. Instead of having to do a select for each line. Furthermore i could batch insert the billing line at the end of the flow.

How do i go down the correct path for my design using Spring Batch?

Comment: And why would you need a new job per line for that? This can be done in a single job with the normal chunk processing. Trying to create a job per line is only adding complexity and will (I suspect) hurt performance. Just write a processor that returns `null` when there is no calculation to be made, which will simply skip that row.

Comment: Because i want to know the job status of each line, and if the processing of that one line should fail i would want the ability to restart only that. Spring Batch might not be the solution for this, which is also why i'm asking this. If you see the other Question linked to at the top, it will make more sense what i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Collect the failed lines, write them to an error file and submit that file again if needed. Or put all lines in a staging table, update a boolean field (processed or something like that). There are multiple solutions which are better then creating a job for each line.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, although i was wondering if i could get Spring batch to do this for me, but that does not seem to be how you use it.

Comment: Well of course you can by putting a queue of sorts in the middel or launch a job but do you really want to start job per line, performance and memory wise (and probably database wise) not really the best solution. Just create a single job, and keep track of which lines fail (if any) and for those you could (after investigation) launch a new job by supplying the lines again.

Comment: A solution with a staging table might even make more sense because you can then have 2 independent jobs. 1 for filling the table and another reading the to be processed records (and setting a boolean property if processed).

Comment: This was just one example, we have multiple Task types that have the requirement of a line (can fail, show status on webpage, ability to restart) So i was looking for a more general solution i could use for all my different Tasks, instead of having to do specific staging table / Task status logic for each Task type. However it seems Spring batch is not the right tools for this. Would you agree?

Comment: And why wouldn't that be doable with a single staging table? Multiple jobs for specific line types. I don't really see the problem here... I'm just questioning your approach of a single job for each line, which is basically comparably to a 1+N select problem (but now for jobs). You could also combine Spring Batch and Spring Integration to do processing/routing for different types of messages. But I would probably go for a staging table and make that usable for different jobs. There is no general approach to solve this (or any other problem) what works for me might not work for you.

Comment: Then we move towards using the single staging table as some kind of queue. Multiple Jobs would do selects and update the same table. Some Jobs would run every hour and some would run on demand maybe every second. See this: https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/

Comment: That is the whole point of a staging table. Also do you really want a queue with millions of messages on it? You would also need a jon cleaning the table  now an then. Again as stated there are multiple solutions possible. What is the best depends on your project and isn't going to be answered in a question on stack overflow...

Comment: if you insist on individual jobs per line, did you look into a asynchronous message oriented approach? like one spring batch which fills a queue for an ESB or similar

Comment: For anyone wondering, I decided to go with a staging approach, however there is only one process polling this staging table. The process will place the job back into a real Queue (AMPQ), where the actual task will then be picked up. Thanks for all your input!